# Annotating PDFs using Wacom tablet on Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, annotations

I recently got a Wacom Bamboo tablet and I'm looking at ways of annotating PDFs with it. My desktop and laptop both run Fedora 20. I would essentially need some piece of software where I can easily do freehand annotations and which works well with a tablet. Are there any for Linux? If there aren't any then anything free for Windows that works under Wine could be useful.

Does anyone have any experience doing what I'm trying to do with a tablet under Linux?

Comment: [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/), maybe? It does add the annotations as an additional layer to the PDF, though (no "proper" PDF annotations as specified in the format).

Comment: OP, did you find anything?

Comment: Xournal does the job for pdf annotation

Answer (score 1):

I've built an open source GUI tool that makes use of Inkscape to do PDF annotations. Inkscape has great support for tablets.

https://github.com/oxplot/pdfrankenstein

Answer (score 0):

There is the java-based [jarnal](http://jarnal.wikispaces.com/). However, jarnal doesn't have a built-in pressure sensitivity for tablets like Xournal.